# Xcode 5 - Unsued Variable warnings - Creating Picker View in IOS -Part 2 - What am I missing?

Tags: xcode, warnings, uipickerview

I am new to IOS programming and was going thru what should be an easy to utilize and understand tutorial at the following address `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twQ6UjhF1Ms'

I am getting warning (**)  at this section of the viewcontroller.m file

```
NSString *meat = Meats[MeatRow];               **unused variable"meat"
NSString *cheese = Cheeses [CheeseRow];        **unused variable"cheese"
NSString *bread = Breads [BreadRow];           **unused variable"bread"

NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You ordered a %@ and %@ on %@ Bread"];   ** More "%" conversions than data arguments
```

Here is the viewcontroller.h code

```
 //
//  ViewController.h
//  PickerViewPart2
//
//  Created by  on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 . All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#define kMeatComponent 0
#define kCheeseComponent 1
#define kBreadComponent 2


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *Meats;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *Cheeses;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *Breads;




- (IBAction)makeSandich:(UIButton *)sender;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sandwichLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;

@end
```

and the Viewcontroller.m code if it helps any one. I am lost or else been looking at it way to long to find what the issue is:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  PickerViewPart2
//
//  Created by  on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 . All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize Meats, Cheeses, Breads, picker;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Meats = @[@"Bologna", @"Turkey", @"Ham", @"Chicken", @"Tuna", @"RoastBeef"];
    Cheeses = @[@"Swiss", @"Cheddar", @"Feta", @"American", @"Pepper Jack"];
    Breads = @[@"Wheat", @"White", @"Rye", @"Sour Dough", @"Pumpernickel"];

    Meats = [Meats sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    Cheeses = [Cheeses sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    Breads = [Breads sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];



}
-(void) didReceiveMemoryWarning{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
                                }

- (IBAction)makeSandwich:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSInteger MeatRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kMeatComponent];

    NSInteger CheeseRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kCheeseComponent];

    NSInteger BreadRow =[picker selectedRowInComponent:kBreadComponent];

    NSString *meat = Meats[MeatRow];
    NSString *cheese = Cheeses [CheeseRow];
    NSString *bread = Breads [BreadRow];

    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You ordered a %@ and %@ on %@ Bread"];

    _sandwichLabel.text=msg;

}

#pragma mark - UIPickerCView Datasource & Delegate Methods

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
   return 3;

}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   if (component == kMeatComponent)
       return [Meats count];
       else if (component == kCheeseComponent)
           return [Cheeses count];
       else
           return [Breads count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   if (component == kMeatComponent)
       return Meats[row];
    else if (component == kCheeseComponent)
        return Cheeses[row];
    else return Breads[row];

}

- (IBAction)makeSandich:(UIButton *)sender {
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using any of the varriable "meat,cheese,bread" try this updated code this will surely clear the warning from your code.

```
NSString *meat = Meats[MeatRow];               **unused variable"meat"
NSString *cheese = Cheeses [CheeseRow];        **unused variable"cheese"
NSString *bread = Breads [BreadRow];           **unused variable"bread"

NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You ordered a %@ and %@ on %@ Bread",meat,cheese,bread];   ** More "%" conversions than data arguments
```

Comment: 2intor -- This was exactly the issue! I watched the same video again and they never show to enter the line like you have it but of course when they compile and run theirs all works well.  Thank you very much for this info!! Is this a de\ifference between the version the use and Xcode5?